# "may" followed by a limiting clause

Tags: conditionals, subordinate-clauses

I would like to get a sense of the implications of a phrase that begins with "may", but is followed by a limitation or qualifier.

For example:

"A lawyer may, no later than 10 days after being provided with the opposing party's motion, raise an objection."

My questions are:

What is this type of sentence called?; Is "may" used instead of "must" only to extend to the lawyer the option or raising an objection?; and If the objection is not raised within ten days, can the sentence be interpreted as negating the lawyer's option to raise an objection and/or is it suggestive that the lawyer acquiesces or accepts the opposing party's motion?

Any comment / interpretation would be appreciated.

Comment: It's just a shorter way of writing "A lawyer may raise an objection, but they may only do so no later than 10 days after being provided with the opposing party's motion." // What may be implied by / inferred from a lawyer's not using this opportunity is hardly on-topic on a site looking at the mechanics of the language. Which we find difficult enough.

Comment: Thank you Edwin - fair point.  However, what type of sentence is this when there is a conditional word followed by a limitation on the conditional?

Comment: 'May' here denotes permission. This is the deontic sense of 'may' = 'is/are allowed to' rather than the epistemic usage (= 'might possibly'); I think you're confusing the two.

Comment: 'May' is a modal auxiliary (verbal) and the stuff between the commas is an adverbial phrase.  You could move the adverbial phrase around without changing the meaning of the sentence.